# Rigidbody2D.AddForce not works as expected

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collider

I make a function to push the player back when it collide with enemy but when it collide from the side of the enemy nothing happen but when the player jump and collide from top-down the function works.
[image]

when collide from the side.
[image]
and it just works from top-down collide.

And here is my scripts:

```cs
 private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
             Vector2 pushDirection = (transform.position - collision.transform.position).normalized;
             rb2D.AddForce(pushDirection * pushForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does your rigibody have friction on the ground? It might be that the impulse isn't enough to slide the character on the ground. What happens if you increase the impulse or decrease friction?

Comment: I have setup everything perfectly and I have increase decrease friction too but nothing changed

Comment: just write a Debug.log("SOMETHING HERE") before your if statement to see if OnCollisionEnter2D is called or not when you hit the enemy. so you can track your problem more easier.

Comment: you can see in the images I haved posted, I had write Debug.Log("PUSHED") to keep track what was happening. When collide from the side the function was called but nothing happen.